# Cisco phone display name change

Tags: voip

I am trying to change name on cisco ip phone 7942. I changed the name in directory number configuration and in phone configuration of phone on CUCM. I did reset of phone too. But still showing the old name. Any suggestions what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 areas to set the name within the a directory number configuation page.  This changes the displayed name for ringout, ringin, and appearance on the phone.  Make sure you are changing all 3 as well as the associated ASSCI lines.